# Is there any way to capture the message on SAP screen by UFT

Tags: testing, automation, abap, hp-uft, sap-gui

After running a program in SAP EM (transaction code: `SE38`), I got the following message screen indicating that the execution is successful.
[image: SAP EM Screen: Successful Message]

But is there anyway to capture the text in this message by UFT (like "successful", and the output file name, so UFT will know which file to find when checking the test result)?

Answer (score 0):

UFT is the best tool if you are automating SAP applications.
It is easy to capture any text on the screen.

1. Open Object Spy and go to add new object.
2. Highlight the text that you want to pick.
3. Add that object (in which the text is present) in your Object Repository.
4. Drag that object in your Action or Function Library and use the method GetROProperty(innertext)

Hope it helps!